# How to draw custom routes in Google maps?

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin

i'm working with Xamarin crossplatform and i want to draw custom route. App needs to draw the route from one place to another exactly which the user using, not alternative routes.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this link may be it's help you

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polyline-map-overlay/

you can Get RouteCoordinates Position using google direction map API.

Comment: Exactly what i'm looking for . Thanks for response 